# Summation in differentiability proof

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading through the following proof on derivatives, but I'm having trouble understanding one specific part.

The proof states: Let $ n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} $ and $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be defined by $ f(x) = x^{n+1}$. Then, for $ x \neq a $

$$\frac{f(x)- f(a)}{x-a} = \frac{x^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{x-a} = \sum_{k=0}^n x^{n-k}a^k $$

Could someone explain how you would get that summation? How are they equal to each other?

Comment: This is a common factorisation trick: multiply $x-a$ to the term on the RHS. Then you should get a difference of two summations, and you should notice that a lot of things cancel out (try it for small $n$ like $n=1,2$ to get an intuition). What you'll end up with is $x^{n+1} - a^{n+1}$

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand. Also, the index of the summation is k but I should be using n = 1, 2?

Comment: @super do you know the summation expression for $x^n - a^n$ ? This is it.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n x^{n-k} a^k 
&= x^n \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^k \\
&= x^n \frac{1 - \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{n+1}}{1 - \frac{a}{x}} \\
&= \frac{x^{n+1} - a^{n+1}}{x-a}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How do you obtain step 3 when you don't know the identity already?

Comment: How else would you simplify?

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{align}
(x-a)\cdot \left(\sum_{k=0}^n x^{n-k}a^k \right) &= (x-a)(x^n + x^{n-1}a + \dots + xa^{n-1} + a^n ) \\
&= (x^{n+1} + x^na + \dots + x^2 a^{n-1} + xa^n) \\
& -(x^na + x^{n-1}a^2 + \dots + xa^n + a^{n+1} )\\\\
&= x^{n+1} - a^{n+1}
\end{align}
To get the last equal sign, notice that a lot of terms cancel each other out. So, all there is to this is to expand everything out, and see that a huge chunk of terms cancel out. Now, dividing both sides by $x-a$ gives you the last equality.